# NSPredicate truncating string

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios7, nspredicate

I am trying to create `NSPredicate`, but it's truncating my string.

```
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"columnId == 1406093563.91876412345"];
```

But when I print `predicate` it gives me:

```
columnId == 1406093563.918764
```

`predicate` always keeps max 6 digits after decimal point. It's happening with numeric digits only.

Comment: It's probably just rounding the number. Is this causing problems? You definitely should not be using floating-point numbers as column identifiers.

Comment: I think it's not an issue. It's just giving you a round figure after the decimal point. Is that result affects you much in your logic part.

Comment: @jtbandes  i am getting problem in fetching the records , i also have a doubt , my column id is string , but why it getting truncate

Comment: If it is a string then you should put it within `'` `'`. It is being treated as a floating-point number and rounded off.

Comment: @jtbandes k thanks i will give it a try , and let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This number is being [rounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Rounding_modes). If you need to use it as an exact string, you should put it in quotes (`'`).